# Android studio editor showing code in a different format

Tags: android, android-studio, text

I have installed android studio on my windows 10 device and open a project, the editor displays the code in an unusual format, please help.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Follow this**

- File --> Settings --> Editor --> File Encoding

Change your Global Encoding to `UTF-8`
and Project Encoding 
see the image you will get answer

[image]

Comment: thanks its solved, File ->Settings-> Editor->Fonts and changing font options