# build.gradle Project Level Showing Unreadable Format ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I don't know this is right platform for this question or not

In my PC i newly installed Android Studio

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

it work fine but after some time when i run my app its show error

```
startup failed:
build file '~/Mymusicapp/build.gradle': 2: unexpected char: 0x1A @ line 2, column 1.

   ^

1 error

Open File
```

When i opened File Project level Gradle Module shows

```
�PNG


IHDR   �   �   � -�  �IDATx���!N+Q��*��$h�@"�$MH�SB�Q�`(�t�w��if8}D3W����ϝ�IοX��J����,��z������/t��)'��������`zz���� ��LO0_��`zz����������`n��`zz�������Ce  �|�ê��<�kkKO���"'7��哿����^[[zz=�<���v��j==/9�� �������`� ==��� ���
��LO0==��0==��� ���
��LO0==;9�h�ӳ���s��X.?����_�N��{G�u��x�W��zvrL�ˍʿH�����0=� �0�`z��`N0�� � `z��`0� �0=� 3p��`����N�'ω����s�4�#����˜d^���C/_@�����Ik��U�z��2'i��� ��oO0���������`��`z��`0� �0=� 3���`����0�� L0��`�����D���vr�Q�g
```

[image]

I dont know what happens with studio or my project,
same unreadable string in my some class file

Comment: Did you tried **File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart**?

Comment: @NirajNiroula yea i  tried **File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart** but not worked did u know why this happens ?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630929/4961662

Comment: @MilanPansuriya thannks but its not a image already set File Encoding UTF-8

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki for your studio you can change your encoding formate to UTF-8

Comment: @MilanPansuriya already setted sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Android project in Android Studio and follow the below steps:

1. Delete **.gradle**, **.idea** & **build** folder from the root directory
2. Delete **build** folder inside `app` module
3. Apply **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart** -> **Invalidate and Restart** option
4. While the Android Studio is being restarted, navigate to your user folder, which generally has **.gradle** folder. Delete the **.gradle** folder in your computer's user directory.
5. Open the Android project again and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: created zip file of project and open in other computer it show all with orignal formate with class file and gradle module why this happen with my computer or studio any idea why this happened

Comment: Not sure but something's wrong with you Android Studio for sure. Did the above steps work for you?

Comment: thanks for your answer but not yet tried i waited one hour but no one answer then i created new project i want to know why this happen ? what wrong with my studio

Comment: it's bug in android studio. not working for me, i open same fine in notepade++ showing original code

Answer (score 2):

In some cases *Invalidate Caches / Restart* was not enough:

1. Delete **.gradle**, **.idea**, & **build**
2. Delete **build** folder inside modules (`app`, ..)
3. Close Android Studio
4. Delete **C:\Users\xxxxxx\.AndroidStudio3.X\system\caches**

Comment: C:\Users\xxxxxx\.AndroidStudio3.X\system\caches worked for me